# Trouble with if else statement

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I have created some R code to create a data frame with a list of dates (1st of each month spanning from April 2013 to July 2022) in the 1st column and 12 additional columns labelled by each of the respective months. I want to put a 1 in the month column if the date is in that month and 0 if not.

I have managed to generate the below code which creates everything I want apart from the fact that column 13 - 'dec' returns all 0's and I cannot figure out why.

Would someone be able to advise why this is happening?

```
mc_mon <- seq(as.Date("2013/04/01"), as.Date("2022-07-01"),  by="month")
mc_mon <- as.data.frame(mc_mon)

month_indicator_mat <- data.frame(mc_mon$mc_mon,
                                  jan=vector(mode = "integer", length = nrow(mc_mon)), 
                                  feb=vector(mode = "integer", length = nrow(mc_mon)),
                                  mar=vector(mode = "integer", length = nrow(mc_mon)),
                                  apr=vector(mode = "integer", length = nrow(mc_mon)),
                                  may=vector(mode = "integer", length = nrow(mc_mon)),
                                  jun=vector(mode = "integer", length = nrow(mc_mon)),
                                  jul=vector(mode = "integer", length = nrow(mc_mon)),
                                  aug=vector(mode = "integer", length = nrow(mc_mon)),
                                  sep=vector(mode = "integer", length = nrow(mc_mon)),
                                  oct=vector(mode = "integer", length = nrow(mc_mon)),
                                  nov=vector(mode = "integer", length = nrow(mc_mon)),
                                  dec=vector(mode = "integer", length = nrow(mc_mon)))

for(i in seq_along(1:nrow(month_indicator_mat))){
for(j in seq_along(2:13)){
       if(j==2){if(substr(month_indicator_mat[i,1],6,7) == "01") {month_indicator_mat[i,j] <- 1}}
  else if(j==3){if(substr(month_indicator_mat[i,1],6,7) == "02") {month_indicator_mat[i,j] <- 1}}
  else if(j==4){if(substr(month_indicator_mat[i,1],6,7) == "03") {month_indicator_mat[i,j] <- 1}}
  else if(j==5){if(substr(month_indicator_mat[i,1],6,7) == "04") {month_indicator_mat[i,j] <- 1}}
  else if(j==6){if(substr(month_indicator_mat[i,1],6,7) == "05") {month_indicator_mat[i,j] <- 1}}
  else if(j==7){if(substr(month_indicator_mat[i,1],6,7) == "06") {month_indicator_mat[i,j] <- 1}}
  else if(j==8){if(substr(month_indicator_mat[i,1],6,7) == "07") {month_indicator_mat[i,j] <- 1}}
  else if(j==9){if(substr(month_indicator_mat[i,1],6,7) == "08") {month_indicator_mat[i,j] <- 1}}
  else if(j==10){if(substr(month_indicator_mat[i,1],6,7) == "09") {month_indicator_mat[i,j] <- 1}}
  else if(j==11){if(substr(month_indicator_mat[i,1],6,7) == "10") {month_indicator_mat[i,j] <- 1}}
  else if(j==12){if(substr(month_indicator_mat[i,1],6,7) == "11") {month_indicator_mat[i,j] <- 1}}
  else if(j==13){if(substr(month_indicator_mat[i,1],6,7) == "12") {month_indicator_mat[i,j] <- 1}} }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `replace` numeric month number of a vector of zeros with `1`, might be less tedious.

```
mc_mon <- seq(as.Date("2013/04/01"), as.Date("2022-07-01"),  by="month")
res <- data.frame(mc_mon, `colnames<-`(t(sapply(as.numeric(substr(mc_mon, 6, 7)), \(x) 
                                                replace(numeric(12L), x, 1))), month.abb))
res  
#        mc_mon Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
# 1  2013-04-01   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 2  2013-05-01   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 3  2013-06-01   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 4  2013-07-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
# 5  2013-08-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
# 6  2013-09-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
# 7  2013-10-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
# 8  2013-11-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
# 9  2013-12-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
# 10 2014-01-01   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 11 2014-02-01   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 12 2014-03-01   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 13 2014-04-01   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 14 2014-05-01   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 15 2014-06-01   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 16 2014-07-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
# 17 2014-08-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
# 18 2014-09-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
# 19 2014-10-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
# 20 2014-11-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
# 21 2014-12-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
# 22 2015-01-01   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 23 2015-02-01   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 24 2015-03-01   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 25 2015-04-01   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 26 2015-05-01   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 27 2015-06-01   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 28 2015-07-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
# 29 2015-08-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
# 30 2015-09-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
# 31 2015-10-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
# 32 2015-11-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
# 33 2015-12-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
# 34 2016-01-01   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 35 2016-02-01   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 36 2016-03-01   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 37 2016-04-01   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 38 2016-05-01   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 39 2016-06-01   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 40 2016-07-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
# 41 2016-08-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
# 42 2016-09-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
# 43 2016-10-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
# 44 2016-11-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
# 45 2016-12-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
# 46 2017-01-01   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 47 2017-02-01   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 48 2017-03-01   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 49 2017-04-01   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 50 2017-05-01   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 51 2017-06-01   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 52 2017-07-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
# 53 2017-08-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
# 54 2017-09-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
# 55 2017-10-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
# 56 2017-11-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
# 57 2017-12-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
# 58 2018-01-01   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 59 2018-02-01   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 60 2018-03-01   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 61 2018-04-01   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 62 2018-05-01   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 63 2018-06-01   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 64 2018-07-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
# 65 2018-08-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
# 66 2018-09-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
# 67 2018-10-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
# 68 2018-11-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
# 69 2018-12-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
# 70 2019-01-01   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 71 2019-02-01   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 72 2019-03-01   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 73 2019-04-01   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 74 2019-05-01   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 75 2019-06-01   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 76 2019-07-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
# [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 36 rows ]
```

*Explanation:*

- `as.numeric(substr(mc_mon, 6, 7))` extracts the month from the 6<sup>th</sup> to 7<sup>th</sup> substring and converts to
  numeric, thus getting the x-position where we want a `1`
- `replace(numeric(12L), x, 1)` replaces xth position of a vector out of zeroes with `1`
- `sapply` loops over the x-positions for each month and creates a
  matrix (in contrast to `lapply` which would create a list); the
  result needs to be `t`ransposed
- we set `` `colnames<-` `` in one step using the `month.abb` stored in
  R as a constant (we could do `tolower(month.abb))` to get lowercase)
- finally we combine `mc_mon` and the `sapply` result in a
  `data.frame`.

Comment: Thank you for submitting an answer but I am however struggling to understand your above solution. Would you be able to break the code down at all? Also, are there any packages you require for the above syntax to be recognised?

Comment: @Jack Sure, thanks for asking, please see update. There are no additional packages needed. Just use the initially created sequence `mc_mon`, not the data frame you created in a second step, then it should work.

Comment: Spent ages figuring out why it wasn't working only to reset R to come back to 0 issues. Thank you so much this is super helpful!